# Efficient way to get all $k$-factors of a graph $G$?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

In [Graph factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization), a $k$-factor of a graph $G$ is a spanning $k$-regular subgraph which has the same vertex set as $G$. Now I have a random graph $g$ (i.e. complete graph for simplicity) and I want to obtain all the $k$-factors in a list.

My strategy is

> 1. get the edges and vertex of $G$: `getpairs` and `getvetex`
> 2. create all the subsets of `getpairs`: `allsublist`, which is equivalent to create all the possible subgraphs.
> 3. - check whether each elements (i.e. number) in every subset is repeated $k$ times (i.e. `terms`), which corresponds to check every subgraph is
>      $k$-regular graph.
>    - check each `terms` have the same vertex set `getvetex` of $G$
> 4. store the correct subsets (i.e. $k$-factors) in `selectlists`.
> 5. repeat steps 3-4 (namely the `for-loop`)

Here is the code for the above task:

```
n = 5;
g= CompleteGraph[n];
getpairs = EdgeList[g] /. UndirectedEdge -> List;
getvetex = VertexList[g];

selectlists = {};
kregular = 2;
allsublist = Subsets[getpairs];
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[allsublist], ii++,
   terms = Cases[Tally@Flatten@allsublist[[ii]], {x_, kregular} :> x];
   If[terms!={} && terms==DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@allsublist[[ii]] && SameQ[SortBy[terms,Greater],getvetex],
    AppendTo[selectlists, allsublist[[ii]]];];
 ];
```

For-Loop is quite inefficient and create all `Subsets` will also take long time when there are many edges in the graph with large `n`.

Let's say `n` currently is small `n<=6`, can one get rid of the for-loop? Are there simple ways to do it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How large do you expect your graphs to be? In general you want to avoid loops in Mathematica, but for something like $n=20$, you have $2^{190}$ subsets which is not going to be feasible and may need a procedural approach. Also, how do you feel about isomorphic graphs? May be able to reduce the computation if we can ignore isomorphic graphs.

Comment: Let's say the graph currently is limited to n<=6? if we current ignore the large ```n``` case, get rid of for-loops can still somehow speed up a bit? @bRost03

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One big speed-up you can get is realizing a $k$-regular graph has $kn/2$ edges so you don't have to generate all subsets of the edges. This goes from considering $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ subsets to $\binom{n (n-1) /2}{kn/2}$ which is a large savings. I am still thinking if there's a way to get more savings by constraints involving spanning sets or regular sets. Either way, here's a more functional solution as opposed to your procedural one. For $n=7$, $k=2$ this is 30x faster than your code on my machine.

```
edges[n_] := EdgeList@CompleteGraph[n];
kEdges[k_, n_] := If[OddQ[k n], Print["No k-factors"]; Abort[];, 
  Subsets[edges[n], {k n/2}]]
regularSpanQ[edges_, k_] := Equal @@ Append[Last@Thread[Tally@Flatten[List @@@ edges]], k]
```

then for example

```
With[{k = 2, n = 6}, Graph /@ Select[kEdges[k, n], regularSpanQ[#, k] &]]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! It's a really good point that one can reduce the Subsets with some conditions.

Comment: just one question, will the method ( i.e. `Subsets[edgeslist, {k n/2}]]`) work for non-complete graph such as `PetersenGraph[5,1]` (although many vertices but few edges)? @bRost03

Comment: Yes, that condition is from the fact that your $k$-factor is $k$-regular and has nothing to do with the underlying graph

Comment: the condition `n` is the number of vertex, right?

Comment: @Xuemei Correct